# Running an async function synchronously

Tags: c#, thread-safety, async-await

Sometimes I have the need to call an async function from a non-async function and get the result back synchronously. Therefore I wrote the following helper function to be able to do this in one line.

```
public static T RunSync<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskConstructor)
{
    var signal = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    T result;
    Exception ex = null;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var task = taskConstructor();
            result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception iex)
        {
            ex = iex;
        }
        finally
        {
            signal.Set();
        }

    });
    signal.Wait();
    if (ex != null)
        throw ex;
    return result;
}
```

Is this ok to do or will it behave unexpectedly in some edge cases? I know that writing this kind of async functions in can be tricky and can easily deadlock. That's why I ran it inside a ThreadPool thread which should prevent any kind of deadlock.

I think that this is probably not the most performant way to do it, but preventing deadlocks is more important in my case.

I know that re-throwing an exception is not ideal, but I think this is a compromise I have to make here.

Comment: Does it have any benefit over just doing task.ConfigureAwait(false)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();

Comment: @Anders Good question actually. I think it does. I think your version may deadlock if the task does not use ´ConfigureAwait(false)´ internally.

Comment: [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) shows why code such at this is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory TaskFactory = new TaskFactory(
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None, 
            TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
            TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(this Func<Task<TResult>> asyncFunc)
        => TaskFactory
            .StartNew(asyncFunc)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();

    public static void RunSync(this Func<Task> asyncAction)
        => TaskFactory
            .StartNew(asyncAction)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
}
```

There are several things that worth mentioning:

- Async methods were designed to be used all the way. So, if you call an async I/O operation in the bottom layer then it should be be called in an async fashion till the top layer.
- Async operations are sensitive for `Exception`s. They can behave differently based on how you call them. (They can be swallowed, thrown as an `AggregateException` or thrown normally. Here the `UnWrap` + `GetAwaiter` do the magic for us to be able to handle the exception normally.
- In order to avoid deadlocks the async operation is passed to an other Task, that is where `TaskFactory.StartNew` comes into play.